# AS3 - Keeping a sparse array sparse

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, indexing

I'm working with an array in AS3, which is sparse by default. I make an array and add a value to it at a given position. I nullify it's contents at that index. It retains that index value, but nullifies the contents. The issue is that the length still traces the same. Is there a way to actually *remove* that index without modifying any of the other indexes?

```
ex: 
array:Array = new Array();
array[ 7 ] = new Array();
array[ 16 ] = new Array();
array[ 16 ] = null;
```

Edit: I want the array the array to stay as small as possible, so that in the example above the array would trace as length 7.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. will your data structure always be sparse? 2. do you need methods like unshift, shift, splice and slice?

Comment: 1. Yes. The data will always be sparse. 2. Splice/Slice - Not required if I have other means of removing data from the data structure while maintaining it's sparse-ness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [delete operator](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/operators.html#delete) ... still, length will remain `8` ... setting the value for key `7` to `null` still means, there is a value for key `7`, since `Array` may contain **any** values, including `null`. if you really use sparse arrays, then consider using `flash.utils::Dictionary` ... if key order matters, then look into `flash.utils::Proxy` ... or make some data structure, that does not use array access, but has some `getVal` and `setVal` methods instead ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: Are you sure? The following: `arr:Array = []; arr[200] = "test"; arr[500] = "test2"; delete arr[500]; trace(arr.length);` traces 501 as length.

Comment: It seems you are right. Who knows, maybe the behavior actually was as a claimed, when I first gave this answer that half a decade ago :D Still, the rest applies ;)

Comment: Ha. Well, I think I've finally found a reason to use a Dictionary after all these years!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
array.splice(7,1)
```

[splice()](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/Array.html#splice%28%29)

Comment: This changes the indexes of all elements after 7.